# Assets are not getting update in for-loop

Tags: javascript, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to use for-loop in the transaction. The for-loop basically creates new assets, ie. I am creating a new asset on each iteration.

The problem is that each time the loop iterates the value of `vals.length` remains zero(0). And if I try to do `console.log(vals)` then too it shows null array even when loop iterates for `i=1,2,3...`

But once whole transaction function gets completed then I am able to see the assets in UI.

### model.cto

```
asset Net identified by NetNumber{
    o String NetNumber
    o Integer totaltransaction
}

transaction GenerateNet {

}
```

### logic.js

```
/**
* submit an order
* @param {org.demo.invoice.GenerateNet}
* @transaction
*/
async function GenerateNet(){
    var amt = [200, 500, 700];
    var netNumber = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'];
    for(var i=0; i < amt.length; i++){
        let netRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.demo.invoice.Net');
        let vals = await netRegistry.getAll();
        console.log(vals.length); 
        console.log(vals);
        let newNetting = factory.newResource('org.demo.invoice','Net', netNumber);
        newNetting.totaltransaction = amt[i];
        await nettingRegistry.add(newNetting);
    }
}
```

I want to see the value of vals.length to be 1,2,3 as the iteration goes on.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to read your own writes, ie you are storing an asset in a registry, then trying to read that registry to get back the asset you have written. This is not possible in hyperledger fabric. It doesn't allow you to read your own writes, you can only read the last committed state, see http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/readwrite.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

New assets are not added to the ledger until the transaction is endorsed. So, at the time the code is run, none of the assets are actually added, they are *scheduled* to be added if/when the transaction is approved.

In other words, you cannot add an asset and read it inside the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop will not wait for the asynchronous tasks to finish before continuing to the next iteration. What you could do is use recursion instead:

```js
var amt = [200, 500, 700];
var netNumber = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'];

async function GenerateNet(i = 0){
    let netRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.demo.invoice.Net');
    let vals = await netRegistry.getAll();
    
    console.log(vals.length); 
    console.log(vals);
    
    let newNetting = factory.newResource('org.demo.invoice','Net', netNumber);
    
    newNetting.totaltransaction = amt[i];
    
    await nettingRegistry.add(newNetting);

    const nextIndex = i++;
    if (nextIndex < amt.length) {
        return GenerateNet(nextIndex);
    }
}

await GenerateNet();
// All iterations have finished
```

Since you're returning the result of `GenerateNet` in each recursion, calling `await GenerateNet()` will resolve when *all* iterations have finished.

Comment: But this is Hyperledger Composer's logic.js, how can I call `await GenerateNet();` without specifying whether it is a transaction. This will show **SyntaxError**